# Extract gps data from a dashcam video

Tags: php, video

I have a dashcam video which is recorded via dashcam and i want to extract the GPS data from the video. In a dashcam viewer software, it is capable to extract and export the data in excel format. I wonder if this process can be replicated using PHP.

Here is the Video embedded with the GPS
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpPcd.jpg)

And here is the exported csv file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x22Tf.png)

Comment: Extracting it from the video image might be quite difficult, but knowning that the dashcam viewer software can export the GPS data tells me that the GPS data is either embedded in the video file (as data, not as an image), or is present in a seperate file. To get any futher we would need to have a video file, the exact make of the dashcam and its software. Lastly: PHP would not be my first choice for doing this, why is it yours? Or: You can already extract the GPS data, why do it in another way?

Comment: Im trying to replicate the software with revisions as per required by the client

Comment: also what other programming language do you recommend

Comment: I can't answer that last question because I know too little about your problem. However PHP is normally used for websites, some data processing and other stuff, but clearly not for recognizing characters in, or parsing, a video-stream. It can probably do it, but I would recommend a programming language with a real compiler. It's just faster at doing these things and you might find more useful tools and libraries.